# linq-to-sql InsertOnSubmit

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I have an object model that's mapped to a database table. The update query looks like this for now:

```
public MyObjectModel CreateNewRecord(MyObjectModel TheNewObject)
{
  using (MyDataContext TheDC = new MyDataContext())
  {
    TheDC.MyTable.InsertOnSubmit(TheNewObject);
  }

  return TheNewObject;
}
```

That code is not working for the insert part (it tells me that InsertOnSubmit has some invalid arguments). In addition, I'd like to return the inserted object so that I can get the value of the primary key of the inserted item.

What do I need to change?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Of what type is `TheDC.MyTable`?

Comment: @MatthiasKoch: when I go in the linq-to-sql classes to see the definition, I have something like "public System.Data.Linq.Table<ObjectModel> TableName"

Comment: @MatthiasKoch: ok, I think got it. I had to create an object of type MyTable and then copy the properties from the MyObjectModel object to the MyTable object. Thanks. Still working on returning the primary key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `MyTable` is of type `Table<ObjectModel>`, you can only add objects of type `ObjectModel`. Try to create your `MyObjectModel` class with all of its properties in the linq2sql designer.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure that in `MyTable.InsertOnSubmit(TheNewObject)` the new object is the type `MyTable` can recieve. Then call `SubmitChanges()`:

```
public MyObjectModel CreateNewRecord(MyObjectModel TheNewObject)
{
  using (MyDataContext TheDC = new MyDataContext())
  {
    TheDC.MyTable.InsertOnSubmit(TheNewObject);
    TheDC.SubmitChanges();
  }

  return TheNewObject;
}
```

Comment: "InsertOnSubmit has some invalid arguments". Your answer does not solve this.